# Qt Creator projects breaking: "symbols not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, linker-errors

I am programming with Qt Creator on a Mac (High Sierra 10.13.4). My projects seem to spontaneously break after a few days of work.

The linker error given is: "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64".

There is nothing wrong with the code - I open, run, close, and reopen projects and they are suddenly broken. I have also tested this with Qt's provided examples, to the same effect. I can copy-paste the code to a new project and compile it with no problem, but it will eventually do the same thing again.

I have attempted deleting the whole debug output folder of the project to give it a fresh start, but it did not make a difference. Same error.

Has anyone had this issue with QtCreator before? Is there a solution?

I have looked up a lot of very similar questions on here, but they all seem to be errors with the code. Just in case it's the same with me, this is all my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "display.h"
#include "frame.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Display w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Display.h & Frame.h are auto-generated.

```
//display.cpp
#include "display.h"
#include "ui_display.h"
#include "frame.h"


Display::Display(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::Display)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget * f = new Frame(this);
    setCentralWidget(f);
}

Display::~Display()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Frame.cpp last:

```
#include "frame.h"
#include "ui_frame.h"

Frame::Frame(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent), ui(new Ui::Frame)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Frame::~Frame()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Check your qt installation. Are you able to run very simple code in qt

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "symbols not found architecture x86 64".  There are a lot of posts about this on StackOverflow already.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, but none of them seem to solve this issue.

Comment: @Mohit yes, until I save, close and reopen the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that the linker error is as given. There's way more to it, and you're not including the meat of the message that actually carries meaningful information allowing to debug this issue. Your problem is possibly with the project becoming internally binary-incompatible, and qmake build system not catching onto it. The issue has nothing to do with Qt Creator. The build is done by qmake and make. You'll see those problems if you build from the command line - which I highly advise you to do.

Assuming the sources are in `/Users/mycaptain/src/myproject`, and that you're using Qt from macports, proceed as follows in terminal:

```
$ mkdir ~/src/build-myproject
$ cd ~/src/build-myproject
$ /opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake ../myproject
$ make
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That's basically what I needed to keep on problem solving. Sadly I am not actually using Qt from Macports but I'll work on building from command line and getting the real error.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install macports and Qt. It'll at least provide you a clear reference. You can have multiple Qt versions installed in parallel, Qt was designed for this -- you select the version to use based on which `qmake` you run. A `qmake` executable = a particular Qt installation.